# Combine rows by consecutive timestamp

Tags: sql

I have an input table as below:

| name | time | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| one | 2022-11-22 19:00:00 UTC | 12 |
| one | 2022-11-23 7:00:00 UTC | 24 |
| one | 2022-11-23 19:00:00 UTC | 10 |
| one | 2022-11-24 7:00:00 UTC | 20 |

My expected output is:

| name | time | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| one | 2022-11-22 | 36 |
| one | 2022-11-23 | 30 |

Explanation:

1. I have to group-by 2 consecutive timestamps, the prev date 19:00:00 UTC and the next date 7:00:00 UTC and name the row with the prev date.
2. Sum the price for each 2 consecutive rows.

Approach:
As I understand, I have to use partition by on the time column, but I cannot figure out how to combine with exact timestamps.

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with cte as (
select name,
       time,
       price,
       (row_number() over (partition by name order by time)+1) div 2 as group_no
  from consec_data)
select name,
       min(time)  as time,
       sum(price) as price
  from cte
 group by name, group_no;
```